# Ignore Xcode warnings when using Cocoapods

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings, cocoapods

I use quite a lot third party libraries which have many warnings in it, after the latest Xcode updates. (for example the Facebook SDK pod)
Now all these warnings are shown in my Xcode on the place I want to see my own warnings or errors.

Is there any way to ignore these errors? Fixing them won't help, since after every "pod install" the changes are discarded.

Answer (score 1102, accepted):

Add to your Podfile:

```
platform :ios

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Then execute: `pod install`

Comment: How do I include that? Currently I use 
s.dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
s.inhibit_all_warnings!
and I get the following error:
undefined method `inhibit_all_warnings!' for #<Pod::Specification for MyApp(1.0)>

Comment: I’ve expanded the example a bit to make the intent more clear.

Comment: How can I solve the following problem: I want the warnings to be hidden for some pods, but not for all of them.

Comment: @krausefx Sorry, didn’t see your comment. For posterity sake, you can now disable warnings on a per-pod basis, as shown in the Podfile docs: http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#inhibit_all_warnings_bang

Comment: Rebuild pods after adding this line. i.e. pod update

Comment: What if I want to enable warnings again?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Remove the directive and run `pod install` to regenerate the Pods.xcodeproj.

Comment: What does the `inhibit_all_warnings!` command translates into on Xocde? "Inhibit all warnings" on Xcode seems to be disabled for the general `Pods` and the individual `Pods-Foo` targets. I cannot find the Xcode build settings that makes the *Cocoapods* subproject ignore warnings. I want to enable `inhibit_all_warnings!` on the Podfile and then disable warnings for just one pod on the Xcode subproject.

Comment: Note that this doesn't preclude warnings (issues) from appearing during the `Analyze` phase. I've offered some suggestions for that in a different answer.

Comment: @teja has posted the correct answer below --> Much simpler and cleaner

Comment: Also, if you only want to disable the warnings from a certain Pod, and that pod has dependencies that it pulls it, then any warnings from those pods don't get hidden. You have to explicitly put the dependency in your podfile too, so you can set the :inhibit_warnings => true part on it.

Comment: After adding this line, you need to run `pod install` and build the project again. This should remove all warnings from pods

Comment: Doesn't work for me, in Pods build settings it appears with NO. I have also the individual setting per pod and it appears with YES but i still see the warnings

Answer (score 40):

You can search for "inhibit_all_warnings" in your Xcode build settings of the PodBundle in your project-workspace. Set the value to "YES" and it will hide all your Pod file warnings.

If you do it to your workspace it will hide all your project warnings also.

Comment: This is a simpler solution, set this on the pods project and it only disables pod related warnings, not your project warnings. No need to re execute the pod install.

Comment: Not recommended! With the next `pod install` this setting is overridden, so better set it in Podfile!

Comment: Personally I do like this so that every update I remember to take a quick look that all warnings and make sure they are neglectable.

Comment: what about for dependencies in a podspec for a local dev pod?

Comment: You may also set `Swift Compiler - Warnings Policies` > `Suppress Warnings` to `Yes`... with the `inhibit_all_warnings` I still had the `'characters' is deprecated: Please use String or Substring directly ` warning in Pods. This setting removed this warning.

Answer (score 21):

Step: 1 Put the below script in your Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS'] = "YES"
        end
    end
end
```

Step 2. Do `pod install`.

Comment: I also had to add the following for Swift Pods:
`config.build_settings['SWIFT_SUPPRESS_WARNINGS'] = "YES"`

Answer (score 8):

Although [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209057/9913) will remove warnings during the build phase, it doesn't appear to completely fix the `Analyze` phase (which caused our CI build to still have issues).

What worked for me (in addition to the accepted answer) was:

- Click on the `Pods` project from the Project Navigator
- Choose the actual `Pod-` Target and click on `Build Settings`
- Filter with the phrase `compiler flags`
- Add a new `Other C Flags` with the value `-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer core` (or whichever analyzers you need disabled) - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389434/9913) provides the full list of flags to try -- please upvote it!

  The version of `clang` in Xcode 6.3.1, though, doesn't seem to include `insecureAPI` so you can remove it from that list. The "current" full list is `-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer alpha -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer core -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer cplusplus -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer deadcode -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer debug -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer llvm -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer osx -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer security -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer unix`

Note that setting this on the `Pods` Project or `Pods` Target *will not work*. I'm not sure why, but you have to set it for each actual `Pod-` target.

You can also set the compiler flags (`-w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -Xanalyzer core` etc.) on a [per-file basis](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Adding%20a%20Compiler%20Flag%20to%20a%20File.html).

I also tried a couple other methods (which may or may not be required in addition to the above). They were performed on the `Pods` Project itself.

---

[1]

- Filter with the phrase `analyzer`
- Make sure `Analyze During 'Build'` is set to `NO`.
- Change all the settings to `NO` (including `Improper Memory Management`)

---

[2]

- Filter with the phrase `warnings`
- Change `inhibit all warnings` to `YES`

<strike>For some reason, even disabling the `Analyze` step in the scheme doesn't seem to work.</strike>

Go to the `Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes` window, click on each `Pod-*` from the list and click the `Edit` button. Click `Build` on the left-hand list, and then *uncheck* `Analyze` on the right-hand side for the `Pod` target.

I am still confused as to why I can't completely disable the Pods from being analyzed, although I expect it might have to do with the "Find implicit dependencies" checked in the scheme's build settings. If that was unchecked, though, it looks like something else would need to happen for the app to link to the pods.

Comment: ***Note:*** Unfortunately, this doesn't help with CI if you exclude Pods and .xcworkspace from your repository - using your .gitignore.

Comment: @RileyE interesting - is there a good reason to exclude those from a repo? If so, does the other technique on this page work for you? (I'm still a relative newbie to iOS development so quite curious to learn more)

Comment: [There is a large divide on whether to include it or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446644/what-goes-into-your-gitignore-if-youre-using-cocoapods). I don't like including it as I prefer to make sure my podfile is always accurate and I've found some conflicts between different user's Podfile.lock and .xcworkspaces. It's simply a preference to users with strongly debatable pros and cons.

Comment: @RileyE thanks for the information! So if we did exclude Pods/.xcworkspace there is no workaround for the issues problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Which is why I've been pushing for additional flags on `pod install`.