# Facebook SDK 3.9 Pod install showing warnings when building

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have updated my Podspec to include the latest Facebook SDK 3.9 (of writing) and I am now seeing a bunch of warnings.

Should I be looking to resolve these:
[image]

A few of these should be simple solutions like updating nil to be 0 instead as expected.

What is the best practice, just to leave these for a minor fix release which should resolve them?

For reference and searching:

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type 'NSRegularExperssionOptions' (aka 'enum NSregularExperssionOptions')
>   Unused function 'FBReadIntBigEndian'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing the files locally would not be very helpful, because someday the files will be overwritten.

You can let Facebook know about these issues and while they don't solve it you can ignore the warnings by changing you Podfile to something like this:

```
platform :ios

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

(Podfile copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209057/1777634)).

Answer (score 2):

I filed a bug - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/724535024243347 - to which the Facebook guys replied that it's in my code and it's not their fault.
After which I've submitted a pull request that fixes/suppresses the warnings in their code - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/pull/563
Hopefully they'll integrate that one.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - I had the same issue, so fixed locally and changed the pod not to update, but I see they still exist in later versions. Good work with the pull request and good luck with them accepting it ;)