# Xcode Don't Display Warnings From CocoaPods Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

When building my project I have a lot of warnings from CocoaPods Pods. So other projects that I don't have control of.

What is the suggested way to handle this? I'd prefer to have Xcode only display warnings related to my project. It just gets to be too much if it displays warnings related to projects I don't have control over.

Comment: duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208202/ignore-xcode-warnings-when-using-cocoapods/13209057#13209057

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is two way to get it done:

#### Method 1

1. Go to your pod project's `Build Settings` tab
2. Search for `inhibit_all_warnings` flag
3. Set it to `YES`

It'll suppress all the warning related to the pod project. But when you do next `pod install` the flag will be reset to `NO`.

[image: Inhibit all warning]

#### Method 2

In your `podfile` specify `inhibit_all_warnings!` key like following: (This will avoid the inhibit warning flag resetting with each pod install issue. Do a pod install after adding this flag.).

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyApp' do
   # Your Pods
end
```

Reference: [Podfile Syntax](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html)

Comment: Still showing warnings. I should mention it's not like CocoaPods warnings. It's like warnings inside of the pods themselves. For example: `Pods/FacebookShare/Sources/Share/Content/Link/LinkShareContent.swift:121:13: 'contentDescription' is deprecated: 'contentDescription' is deprecated from Graph API 2.9` or `Pods/DGElasticPullToRefresh/DGElasticPullToRefresh/DGElasticPullToRefreshLoadingViewCircle.swift:35:32: 'M_PI' is deprecated: Please use 'Double.pi' or '.pi' to get the value of correct type and avoid casting.`

Comment: Ok looks like method 2 works. For some reason method 1 was still throwing warnings. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CharlieFish: Both methods are working for me, glad to know method 2 worked for you :) Happy Coding !!!