# Xcode: suppressing all warnings for all external libraries

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

To disable compiler warning I go to **Project** -> **Target** -> **Build Settings** and add flag

```
-w
```

for specific file. This flag disables **all** warnings for the file.

But sometimes **this flag does not work**.

For example, when I run the test, I get warnings for external library [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) (all this files I marked with the flag -w):

> .../Pods/Nimble/Sources/Nimble/Matchers/MatcherProtocols.swift:15:11:
>   'Matcher' is deprecated: Use to Predicate instead
>   .../Pods/Nimble/Sources/Nimble/Matchers/Predicate.swift:170:22:
>   'Matcher' is deprecated: Use to Predicate instead
>   .../Pods/Nimble/Sources/Nimble/Matchers/AllPass.swift:22:27: 'Matcher'
>   is deprecated: Use to Predicate instead
>   .../Pods/Nimble/Sources/Nimble/Matchers/AllPass.swift:76:21: Variable
>   'generator' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
>   .../Pods/Nimble/Sources/Nimble/Matchers/AsyncMatcherWrapper.swift:41:14:
>   'Matcher' is deprecated: Use to Predicate instead

What am I doing wrong and how to get rid of warnings for external libraries that I have no influence on?

Comment: Hey I left my answer, can you confirm it as the accepted answer if it is fine?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Quick Fix**

I see you are using *cocoapods*. 
Cocoapods rewrite your configs each time you run `pod install`. So, you need to add this line in your `podfile` to ignore **all warnings** or **warnings for a specific pod**:

```
# example to ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# example to ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'Alamofire', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

NOTE: *Sometimes it is good to see your warnings and your pod's warnings too, so you could prevent issues in the future.*

Answer (score 3):

By the logs in your question, I see `cocoapods` in your project. Simply add the `inhibit_all_warnings!` flag to your `podfile`, this flag will hide the compilation warnings of third-party libraries installed with `cocoapods`.

More detailed description about using `inhibit_all_warnings!` flag see in [alloy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209057/8564810).