# Hundreds of warnings after updating my Podfile: Warning: [...] is only available on IOS [...]

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I tried to update all my pods. That worked too, but since then I have received hundreds of warnings in Xcode.

```
pod update
[...]
Pod installation complete! There are 12 dependencies from the Podfile and 23 total pods installed.
```

[image]

All warnings look something like this. Before the update, I had none of these.

```
Project:     IOS Deployment Target: 10.0
All Targets: Deployment Target: 10.0
```

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: If anyone has the problem, too: [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209057/4699533). No solution to the problem but a short-term workaround...