# How to ignore warnings from the imported Framework on swift / obj-c

Tags: ios, xcode

On swift / obj-c project, Is there solution to ignore warnings from the imported Framework?

I want to treat warnings as errors. So, I enabled two build settings **GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS** and **SWIFT_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS**.

Turning on the setting is not difficult. But I often encounter problems outside the area I can control. Warning from imported Framework can't be fixed by me.

Is there any options to inhibit warnings in imported Framework? Except for warnings in the imported framework, I want to treat every warnings as error.

Answer (score -2):

Add to your Podfile:

```
platform :ios

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'XXXXXXXXX', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Then execute: pod install

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209057/8069241

Comment: I use carthage instead of cocoapod. Is there any solution for carthage?