# how to fix the warning from installed pods after update Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in programming, I am sorry if my question seems silly. I am trying to build an iOS app using Firebase.

After updating to Xcode 9.3, there are a lot of warnings show up like the image below:

[image]

I suppose this come from the Firebase pods, and maybe the pod hasn't been updated by Firebase. am I right?

so what I have to do? do I have to fix the warning manually or I just have to wait the update from Firebase? and If I still run the program with a lot of warning like that, is the program will run properly ?

here is the pods I use

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.git'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

Comment: They probably haven't updated it to the new warnings in Swift 4.1 & XCode 9.3, you can ignore it and wait for new update i think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warnings are usually just that: warnings. Most likely the code will run just fine and you can just wait for the developers to update their code.

Optionally if you dislike seeing them you can inhibit warnings in your pods within your podfile like this:

```
platform :ios

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

You'll have to run a `pod install` for the change in the project settings to happen.

This will suppress warnings in the pods you pull in and give the developers time to fix the issues.

Source: [Ignore Xcode warnings when using Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208202/ignore-xcode-warnings-when-using-cocoapods)