# Remove deprecated iOS framework warning in specific pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to not see this warning in the Atlas pod since its not my library.

> 'UIMutableUserNotificationCategory' is deprecated: first deprecated in
>   iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationCategory

I am using

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

in my pod file.

I also tried `pod 'Atlas', '1.1.5', :inhibit_warnings => true` which didn't work.

I'm thought if I change the platform from iOS 9 to iOS like this

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

It would no longer show the warning.

**update**

`-Wno-deprecated` worked when I put it in Atlas build settings under `complier flags -> c++ flags`.

**Any way to do this in the podfile?** so a pod install will not break it.

Comment: Have you check this link? Please check the answer with 2 up votes 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208202/ignore-xcode-warnings-when-using-cocoapods

Comment: Tried it now. I wanted to add the -w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-all-checks flag to the specific file but it was already added presumably by the inhibit_all_warnings! I added already.

Comment: Are you using a recent CocoaPods version? 1.5.3 is the current version.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien yes version 1.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Add to your podfile the following statement, and then run `pod install`

```
pod 'YourPodToIgnore', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Comment: I am as noted by the question. I updated the question to make it more visible.

Comment: did you try de-integrating and re-integrating the pods?

Answer (score 0):

> Any way to do this in the podfile? so a pod install will not break it.

In this way you can set it the **build_settings** for every target:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'] = "-Wno-deprecated"
    end
  end
end
```