# Disable some warnings in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I disable some warnings in Xcode? 
I want to disable warnings from R.swift lib. Can I add some `run script` for filtering warnings by prefix `[R.swift]`?
I can't change now localizable strings keys, so I want to disable warnings

[image]

Comment: Integrate R.swift using Cocoapods and follow the solution in this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208202

Comment: Fork the project, fix the warnings, pull request the changes.

Comment: It's not help, because warnings in project .xproj file, not in R.Swift. So I try to add this setting for pod, and call 'pod install'. But warnings didn't disappear after clean and rebuild