# How to Ignore warnings when using new Podfile in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, cocoapods

Hello I implement different library from cocoapod and install Podfile

but I want to ignore the warnings

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208202/ignore-xcode-warnings-when-using-cocoapods

Comment: sound good I'll check thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# example to ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# example to ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'Alamofire', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

**you have to add this line in your podfile.**