# Commit to git after switching to workspace and adding CocoaPods in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods, git-commit

I've just added CocoaPods to my current project in Xcode 5. Of course, CocoaPods created a workspace and I've launched the workspace in Xcode. I see both my project and the Pods project in the workspace.

My project has been under source control (local git + remote Bitbucket repository) since day one. Now I want to commit and add the Pod stuff but I think that my repo is too deep in the workspace--when I try to commit (and I've tried various commits to get the Pod stuff to take) it always errors out.

How can I add my Pods to my repo?  Do I have to delete the old repo and create a new one (git init) at the Workspace level?  (I sure hope not because I'm not that great with git and I have a lot of historical commits in my repo already.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What goes into your .gitignore if you're using CocoaPods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446644/what-goes-into-your-gitignore-if-youre-using-cocoapods)

Comment: I read the article and have decided to commit everything.  Switching my commit window to the flat list I was able to commit all the files in sections.  That's a great other question/answer though...well worth the read.  Thanks Mike D.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, I integrated Cocoapods last week myself and came across problems with the project file: http://guides.cocoapods.org//using/faq.html#%E2%80%9Ccocoapods-has-just-changed-my-entire-pbxproj,-what-gives?%E2%80%9D

Answer (score 14):

## git add .

From the directory enclosing your Xcode project, simply execute a `git add .`. Documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

## Explanation

You likely had the following hierarchy prior `pod init`:

[image]

In all likelihood, your `git` setup starts at the directory enclosing `.xcodeproj`.

After `pod install`, the hierarchy did not change. You merely have more files at the same level:

[image]

The `.xcworkspace` is next to `.xcodeproj`, not above. You are free to execute

```
git add .
```

...followed by

```
git commit -m "message"
```

...assuming that `.gitignore` is set up properly, and wether or not you prefer to commit the `Pods` directory.