# git push ignore cocoapods

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

I have been developing an iOS application for a few months. Now, I want to push it on bitBucket. The problem is git push ignore all files related to cocoapods (e.g., project.xcworkspace Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods, etc.)

Is there any way to push these files?

Comment: Did you 'git add' those files? Did you commit your changes? Are you using a .gitignore file that specifies rules for those files or filetypes?

Comment: I am quite new to git. I tried to commit add and push. But don't know about gitignore file.

Comment: Well, if the files aren't being pushed, you haven't told git to start tracking them in your repository. In any case, this free ebook is a good place to start with git: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: How can I tell git to start tracking them in my repository?

Comment: 'git add filename' is the command you need. However, I strongly advise you to read up more on git before going any further, as it is apparent that you don't have a basic working knowledge of the system at this point. The aforementioned ebook has all the information you need.

Comment: I use git add * at the beginning.

Comment: Well, if you add new files to your project, you need to add them as well. If you want to start tracking files in a subdirectory, you need to git add that subdirectory as well.

Comment: So, why I use "git add *", it add all folders (including all sub-files) except cocoapod stuffs? I have a knowledge of svn. Even, the idea of git is a little bit different in comparison to svn. But the meaning of commands like commit, add , etc... still are the same.

Comment: There are some subtle differences between the commands, and some not so subtle (e.g. checkout) so you may want to read up. Check your .gitignore file. If it exists, it'll be in the root directory of your project (note the preceding '.').

Answer (score 1):

Open your `.gitignore` file with a text editor (note: it's a hidden file). It's likely that it has lines like:

```
Pods/
Podfile
```

or:

```
Pod*
```

The line `Pods/` is often added in some default `.gitignore` files found in various places around the net ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065359/1033581)), and it tells `git` to not push CocoaPods dependencies.

Well, the solution is to remove or comment out those lines (comments are done with a `#` character in your `.gitignore`).

Answer (score 0):

Using git add -A to add everything.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed? I'm facing the same problem, I tried it without any useful result