# git commit error: large file detected

Tags: ios, git

Hi I'm developing an application xcode for ios 8.1 I have used googleMaps framework for autocomplete feature. when I try to push my project in Git I was getting large file detection error. later have tried with git lfs and tracked the file detected by git (i.e., GoogleMaps) then I tries push still showing the same error.

```
iSpire-Solution-1:productionPreFinal 2$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 762, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (693/693), done.
Writing objects: 100% (762/762), 83.82 MiB | 4.14 MiB/s, done.
Total 762 (delta 179), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: e7a6ab16d31c340cad67b08ee53ee032
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMaps is 113.56 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/ispire123/AutoM8.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ispire123/AutoM8.git'
iSpire-Solution-1:productionPreFinal 2$ git lfs track
Listing tracked paths
    Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMaps (.gitattributes)
```

Please suggest me how can i Manage git lfs. and is there any option reduce the file size of googleMaps frameworks in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: i think this is just a limit with using github, maybe a premium account would lift this limit but im just guessing really

Comment: also if the framework is a pod, you could potentially git-ignore it so it doesnt get committed, then whenever the project is checked out they just need to reinstall the pod

Comment: what is your file size ?

Comment: thanks Fonix git-ignore be a better option for my situation i think.

Comment: because i'm already using paid account.

Comment: Badal Shah: i'ts 113.56 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) as a [dependency manager for your Xcode project](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/cocoapods-dependancy-management-for-xcode/139), consider following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446644/what-goes-into-your-gitignore-if-youre-using-cocoapods) advice and only committing the Podfile as the pods can be regenerated from the Podfile.

This means that you're not committing over [Github's file limit](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/#conditions-for-large-files) and you're keeping your repository streamlined.

To ensure you don't commit any Pods to your repo, just add the `pods/` directory to your/a .gitignore file.