# Best approach : Is it good approach to sync pods file on Github

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I am using some framework which are integrated with pods . So I want to ask is this good approach to sync these framework on gitHub . For example . In my iOS project I have integrated GoogleMap framework, Should I sync this on Github or i should some reference . I am asking this because When i commit this framework it give me memory issues.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there's no "best approach" about what should be ignored concerning your pods dependencies.

One would say that it's better to ignore the pods directory to keep your git repository light, but for someone else would say that your pods dependencies are part and parcel of your app, it won't build without it, so you must commit it.

First I chose to include all my pods in my git repo, but I quickly noted that it could be very annoying, given that each time you update one of your dependencies it blows yp your updated commit files list. Now I just include my Podfile and Podfile.lock files and ignore the Pods repository. **Just make sure to run pod install each time you pull from the repo**.

The main benefit of including all your Pods is to have your project "ready to build", without the need to have CocoaPods installed on your computer to build it first.

For more details, see this related question :
[What goes into your .gitignore if you're using CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446644/what-goes-into-your-gitignore-if-youre-using-cocoapods)