# Github swift repository tagged Objective-c

Tags: github

I've created one pod repository with swift language, after completion of all process it shows Objective-c tagged language for that repository?
Is that anything I've done wrong while creating library?
Library link - https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/KJCurveSlider
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your podfile has downloaded a library that is coded in ObjectiveC. That code is greater than your actual code, thus Github thinks the language is Obj C

I'd recommend looking at [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446644/what-goes-into-your-gitignore-if-youre-using-cocoapods) to solve your problem

Also, [this link](https://gist.github.com/andrewsardone/3889904) describes how to work with cocoa pods with git

Comment: Hi Ronak, You'r right. There was FBSnapshotTestCase Objective-c library been installed through dependency mentioned on pod file in Example. I've removed it, and it shown 'Swift' tagged!