# What is "Pod/***.a Pod/**.dia" file?

Tags: swift, xcode, git

I am using the Cocoapod , RxCocoa , RxSwift and Git.

When I run the  "git status", some warning will show:

> (use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
> modified:   Pods/RxCocoa.d
> modified:   Pods/RxRelay.d
> modified:   Pods/RxSwift.d

I remember "Pod/***.a Pod/**.dia" show too.

How to prevent this in the future?
Must I add something into the `.gitignore` file??

=====================
Edit again:

I viewed the `.gitignore` a few minutes ago.

My project doesn't ignore the `Pods`.
My project ignore the files in this way:

```sh
# Xcode
*.build
*.dia
*.tlog
*.o
*.d
```

In my opinion, I need't ignore the ".d" ".a" ".dia"  files which are in the file "Pods/", need I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ignore Pods altogether:

```sh
echo Pods/>.gitignore
git rm --cached -R Pods/
```

But [ignoring Pods has its Pros and Cons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9446644/6309), so make sure this would work with your development workflow.

---

If your `.gitignore` already had `*.d` for instance, you can make sure that rule applies with:

```
git rm --cached -R Pods/*.d
```

(same for `*.a`, and so on)

Comment: @jiexishede I have updated the answer after your latest update.

Comment: Note to self: That was my **27000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 160 months), a bit less than 6 months after the  [26000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68190336/6309). Before that: [25000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370954/6309), [24000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62688871/6309), [23000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853332/63099), [22000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387243/6309), [21000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856158/6309), [20000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915541/6309), ...