# How to see file history, stashes etc. on source control panel in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to see file history, stashes etc. on my source control panel like below image. How is it possible? By the way, my system is Mac OS

Currently I see only Changes Section

[image]

[Image Reference](https://medium.com/@shrirammano/understanding-git-stash-and-using-it-easily-in-vscode-7da049160097)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing Git Lens extension in VS Code worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.86 (Jan. 2024) should include the ability to view a stash (no GitLens needed)

See [issue 203037](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203037) and [issue 203040](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203040), currently in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

> ### View Stash
>
> 1. Launch the latest version of VS Code Insiders
> 2. Open a folder/workspace that contains a git repository
> 3. Invoke the "Git: View Stash..." command, and pick a stash from the list
>
>    - Confirm that the files from the stash are being opened in the multi-file diff editor
>    - Confirm that latest appears on the left, and changes from the stash appear on the right
> 4. Invoke the "Git: View Stash..." command, and pick the same stash from the list
>
>    - Confirm that the already opened editor is focused, and no new editor is opened

Comment: Note to self: That was my **31000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 184 months), a bit more than 7 months after the [30000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76465759/6309). Before that: [29000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74593456/6309), [28000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72697130/6309), [27000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504269/6309), [26000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68190336/6309), [25000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370954/6309), [24000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62688871/6309), ...

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the top level headline (should be "Source Control" for the Changes section). This will show a menu from which all the displayed sections can be selected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think it works only on Windows. In VS Code on Mac when I click, I don't see them.

Comment: I just tried this in Windows. To get the sections I had to install Git Lens extension. After that I saw all control panels.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Linux either (Ubuntu 20.04)