# How to post my 1st project from Jetbrains academy / hyperskill to github?

Tags: java, github, jetbrains-ide

I started learning java on hyperskill/ Jetbrains academy and finished my 1st project. How to upload it into github if I didn't use IDE, only built in code editor?

Searched info on github and hyperskill but unsuccessful...

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to [install](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) the [GitHub CLI gh](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh), and authenticate with [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)

From there, you can go to your local repository folder, and use [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) to:

- create a new repository on GitHub
- import your local sources

That is:

```bash
# create a remote repository from the current directory
gh repo create my-project --private --source=. --remote=upstream
```